# How display length of branches in phylogenetic tree

Tags: r, phylogeny

Here I have code that draw simple phylogenetic tree from newick format:

```
library(ape)
t<-read.tree(text="(F:4,(  (D:2,E:2):1,(C:2,(B:1,A:1):1):1):1);")
plot(t,use.egde.length=TRUE)
```

i am"displaying" correct length of branches, but i want all branch to have labal with it.
[image]

edit:
i want my plot to look like this:
[image]
I was searching documentation, but I cannot find method to display length of branch in R. How can i do this ?

Comment: Like in `t$egde.length`?

Comment: i want to have length of all branches on the tree, above branches.

Comment: You said you want to "display length of branch in R". I give you the way. If you have more specific request, please make your question more specific.

Comment: Length of branches is correct in my tree, i just want to all branches to have label with that length, for example 4 above F branch

Comment: but how can i use it, to display it on all branches ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it by extracting edge lengths and using `edgelabels()`.

```
# Load package
library(ape)

# Create data
t <- read.tree(text="(F:4,((D:2,E:2):1,(C:2,(B:1,A:1):1):1):1);")
plot(t)
edgelabels(t$edge.length, bg="black", col="white", font=2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is way you can get the plot you want:

```
t$tip.label <- c("F\n4", "D\n2", "E\n2", "C\n2", "B\n1", "A\n1")
plot(t,show.node.label=TRUE, show.tip.label=TRUE)
```

[image: [image]]

However, I don't know of a graceful way to extract out the lengths without doing it manually.

Comment: thank you, but is there a way i display lengths of rest of the branches ?
(F:4,(  (D:2,E:2):1,(C:2,(B:1,A:1): 1):1):1); last branches with "1" length

Comment: May I ask that you update your original question with an image containing precisely what you want to see?  I suspect the answer to your question is no, because the tip labels are the only labels which can be configured according to the interface.  Of course, you can always hack the source code, but this is a lot of work.

Comment: It is easy to do using `edgelabels`, see my answer